# PHP: How to add Languages layer to MVC framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

I am currently working on my own implementation of a MVC framework. I would like to know how to add language layer to my framework so that it could support multiple languages other than english. What's the role of unicode in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks frequently utilize a concept of "localization files" (.po files as a standard) to do UI translation. In your view and controllers, whenever you want to show a piece of text, instead of calling

`echo "Hello"`

You'd do

`echo MyFramework::Translate("Hello")`

That Translate() function just looks up the right .po file, and based on the passed in "ID" of the phrase, returns the desired localized text.

Comment: If you use a static call to do this, you couple your code to your framework. It's better to dependency inject your translation component, else decorate your object with a translation decorator to handle these sorts of things. Static calls pointing toward global mutable state are not the way forward.